# In languages with grammatical gender, how do they determine the gender when a new word has been created?

Tags: linguistic-typology, gender, borrowing

In languages with grammatical gender that has (almost) no morphological relation between the words and the genders(e.g. French), how do they determine the gender of a new word that has been introduced/created?

I think that
as people don't speak based on the grammar but the grammar is based on how people speak, grammatical genders are determined based on in what gender people use the word.

But then, How do ***people*** know in what gender they are to treat the introduced/created word?

This depends a lot on the language, but if you know any example of any language, I'd be glad to know that.

Comment: I think that *decide* is not the right word.

Comment: There has been a project on [Loanword Typology](http://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/files/lwt.html): "we studied lexical borrowing patterns in 41 languages from around the world. ...  For each language, we assembled lexical data for a fixed list of 1460 meanings." They produced a database. Their data can be useful for some testing of the hypothesized rules of adapting a word in languages with genders. Not sure whether they paid much attention to genders in their work. See also the book produced by the project, and http://email.eva.mpg.de/~haspelmt/lwt-guidelines.html to know which data was collected.

Comment: If you find some conclusions about genders in their work, it would be nice if post your findings as an answer here, because it would be interesting to know.

Comment: Have also a look at the search results for ["Loanword Typology" gender](http://scholar.google.ru/scholar?hl=en&q=%22Loanword+Typology%22+gender&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=).

Comment: Wikipedia says that in Quebec French, words that end in consonant sounds in isolation are generally assumed to be feminine. In French, masculine nouns get their final consonant elided in most contexts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the **source language already has genders**, then they will often be taken along to the host language, provided that people in the host language know a little bit about the source language. But there are countless other subtle, complex factors.

***Dutch*** has a **neuter** article (*het*) and the fused/common gender **masculine-femine** (*de*). There are no definite rules for borrowed words, and we never learned any such rules. I would know if there were any, but no: genders are assigned subconsciously. For existing Dutch words, there are some rules, but I think perhaps half the words have genders that feel arbitrary (though fixed) to us. For example, a person will nearly always be masculine or feminine, and words on *-heid* are always feminine; but for most other words you just have to know. The difference between masculine and feminine only comes up with possessive adjectives (*the fork and his?/her? prongs*) and personal pronouns (*not that fork: I saw her?/him? lying over there*). Colloquially, we usually use masculine pronouns for *de* words; in writing, I often have to look up the gender of a word, unfortunately. In the south and in Belgium, I think they don't use masculine by default.

Because we have a word *het huis* in Dutch ("the house"), English *safehouse* will become *het safehouse*, as it is very **similar**. Usually the similarity is less direct; then a word with a similar *meaning* may be picked as the example. For instance, suppose that Japanese **inko* means house (I'm just making this up), then I am more likely to say *het inko*.

However, a second factor is how the word **sounds** compared to words that sound remotely similar. Words on -o are probably more often masculine in Dutch, because of the many Italian and Spanish words on -o, like impresario, virtuoso, amigo, gringo, etc., so I am more likely to say *de inko* because of the sound.

Thirdly, I think many languages have a kind of **"default" gender for (foreign) words**. In German, I was taught that newly borrowed words are normally feminine. So it was easy to learn *die CD* and such (although, if this rule is valid in German, there must be many categories of exceptions). In Dutch, masculine and feminine have all but merged, that is, they have the same article, *de*. For that reason, *de* is much more frequent than *het* (neuter), so that *de* is more likely to be chosen for new words.

Fourthly, there is the possibility that the gender is taken from a **third language**, if that language has already adopted the word and assigned a gender to it. Dutch might follow German in some cases; I don't know how often this really happens.

To all these factors may be apportioned different weights in different circumstances, and they are somehow weighed by the subconscious of the first people who use the word, until at some point it has acquired a commonly accepted gender. It is often unpredictable in my experience.

Note also that it is perfectly possible for a borrowed word to **remain of uncertain gender** indefinitely. We even have some ancient native (inherited) words that we still bicker over (in a good-natured manner, of course). Now a few practical examples.

> Dutch *het net* => **het Internet.** Since *net* means the same thing in Dutch as in English, this one was easy.
>
> *Het koekje* => **de/het cookie.** I'm not sure about this one; I would probably say *de cookie*. Perhaps it is too new, but people do talk about this on a regular basis, have done so for at least a decade, and yet it is still not entirely decided. One would expect such a strong similarity to the Dutch word to lead to *het cookie*, and yet I would say *de cookie*. I feel that perhaps the default gender *de* is just too strong in Dutch. Or perhaps the fact that it is a small object: perhaps those have an extra strong tendency to be *de* words? Hard to say.
>
> **De router, de server:** we have no similar words, but words on *-er* usually indicate an agent, a person even, and people are normally not neuter, so definitely *de router, de server*.
>
> **De absence**: this is the French word, pronounced as in French. It was adopted into Dutch long ago, so I did not witness its introduction. My guess is that the ending *-e* had a strong influence, and simply the fact that it is obviously feminine in French.
>
> **Het communisme**: this probably came from French. For some reason, (nearly?) all words on *-isme* are neuter in Dutch. I have no idea why, because I think they are masculine in all other languages, including French, which doesn't have a neuter gender at any rate. They come from Latin -*ismus*, which is masculine, from Greek *-ismos*, also masculine. Very strange.
>
> **De coating** (as in paint). There is no Dutch equivalent. The ending *-ing* is nearly always feminine in Dutch for non-persons, so *de* (cognate to German *-ung*).
>
> **De axolotl**: nothing at all sounds like or resembles an axolotl, but I think animals are by default *de*, because they are agents (even though we do have plenty of neuter animals).
>
> **De tsunami**: probably *de* because *-i* sounds a bit like Italian or Latin masculine? There is also *de golf* "the wave", *de vloed* "the flood". I'm not sure.
>
> **Het DNA**: hard to say. Perhaps because *Acid* was translated subconsciously as *het zuur* by the first Dutch scientists? Because substances are more likely to be *het*?

Comment: I had always been taught that German loan words default to neutral gender ("das") but clearly it's more complex than that.  http://www.dartmouth.edu/~german/Grammatik/Wortbildung/Fremdwoerter.html

Comment: @tripleee: Perhaps the rule is, in the typical German fashion, "borrowed words are neuter, except... *<20 pages of exceptions and sub-rules>* ".

Answer (score 6):

As a native speaker, let me try to describe it. To be most specific, I will refer Ukrainian and Russian.

Short rules:

1. Keyword: "a **city** of New York"; `city` is masculine, hence most often, city names are masculine as well;
2. Pronunciation: words ending with consonant - masculine; ending with `-e`, `-o` - usually neutral; `-a` - feminine;

---

TL;DR, just if you are curious to details

First, let me remind that grammatical gender (GG) has no relation to lexical meaning of the word; you have just to remember GG of each noun.

Also, although there are three formal GG, there are nouns that are always singular, plural or dual.

Most loanwords belong to the following groups:

- No declension: coffee, cocoa, Bourdeau (wine), Euro (currency), etc;
- Toponyms: America, Tokyo, Mississippi, Himalaya;
- Abbreviations (OUN, USA);
- Noun groups
- Naturally plural or paired items (types of shoes);

---

**General rule**

- Those ending on `-o`, `-e` (many French and Italian words) usually become **neutral**;
- Ending with `-a` become **feminine**;
- Ending with a plosive consonant become **masculine**;
- Ending with "soft sign" (pronounced with a palatalized final consonant) so **feminine**;

**Nouns that do not decline**

They usually used to be proper nouns that later started to mean common terms (whisky, Champagne, Bourdeau, brandy, Euro). *Note they have retained capitalization in English, but in Slavic languages they are regular words, unlike toponyms.*
There's no certain rule, and GG is assigned according to similar existing loanword nouns. For instance, most *non-declining* words borrowed from Romance languages are **neuter** due to their pronunciation (ending with `-e` or `-o`).

There are many exceptions, however:

- RU, UA: `whisky` can be either **masc** or **neutr**;
- RU: `кофе` (coffee) is masculine due to historical reasons: there was an older version `кофий`, ending with a consonant;

**Naturally plural or paired items**

Obviously, they are plural (grammatically, plural and dual are the same). Note that in most declensions, there is no difference between masculine+plural, feminine+plural, and neutral+plural.

- Moccasin - shoes, naturally paired;
- Jeans - naturally plural;

**Noun groups**

If one word has no declension while the other has, the GG of the whole group is given by the word that has declension.

- `Web-page`, where `Web` has no declension while `page` is a common word (**fem**).

**Toponyms**

GG is given according to what category the noun belongs to. Look again at the rule above and think of "the **city** of New York".

- `Mississippi` is a river; river is **fem**, hence, `Mississippi` is as well;
- `Ontario` is a lake; `lake` is **neutral**;
- `San-Francisco` is a city; `city` is **masc**;

There are lots of exceptions here:

- `Hudson`, `Rhein`, although `river`s (fem), are **masc** - probably, due to ending with plosive consonant;
- `Philadelphia`, `Nevada`, are states (`state` is **masc**), is **fem**, again, probably, due to it ends with `-a`;
- RU: `Vienna` is a city (must be masc), but is **fem**;
- UA: `city` is **neutral**, but it does not apply on most city names; For example, `Vienna` is written `Відень` ['videnʲ], and it is **masc**;
- `Apache` is tribe (must be neutral), but is **plural**;

**Abbreviations**

GG is given by the keyword:

- OUN stands for "**Organization** of United Nations", the highlighted keyword is **fem** (all words ending with `-ion` are **fem**)
- USA stands for "United **States** of America", and it is **plural**;
- TCP/IP is an "Internet **protocol**", **masc**;

---

And yes, if the loanword does not apparently belong to any of the groups above, it is often considered by its category or keyword.

Finally, if that was too boring, I have good news: there are lots of exceptions. :)

Comment: Wow, you have many rules! Very different from the way it feels in Dutch: I can't really think of many exact rules, only vague factors that may or may not influence words. Are people taught these rules, or do they strongly intuit these rules? Do all people intuit these rules equally strongly?

Comment: @Cerberus The ultimate judge is a dictionary. Otherwise, it's a pure intuition. Personally, it took me a minute to recall if `Tokyo` is masculine or neutral.

Comment: But most of the other words came to you by intuition quite clearly? // So about this dictionary, how do the editors decide which sex to assign? Do they consciously apply these rules? And how many of the words in your list did you have to look up in a dictionary?

Comment: @Cerberus Those who write dictionaries usually don't invent the language. They formalize the way how the things are. In other words, a loanword if first loaned, mutually agreed regarding its declension, and only then it appears in dictionaries. Only if there are controversial uses, they take decisions. Masculine `coffee` in Russian is the most prominent example since it sounds very similar to neuter.

Comment: @Cerberus the basic rule is that anything ending -а is feminine, anything ending -о and -е are neuter and anything ending with a consonant is masculine. Abbreviations case is determined based on the main noun in the abbreviature. So the only remaining cases are the words ending with -и, -у.

Comment: @Anixx: Right, if your language has such fixed rules for its native words, then it makes sense that they should be applied to foreign words as well. But don't people mess up the sex of abbreviations? They do here. They forget what the head noun was.

Comment: @Cerberus some of the abbreviations become normal nouns over time. For example, ВУЗ (=Высшее Учебное Заведение) now can be written with small letters, "вуз" and has masculine gender even though the word "заведение" is neuter.

Comment: Russian and Ukrainian could be viewed as not being languages "with grammatical gender that has (almost) no morphological relation between the words and the genders(e.g. French)" (from the original question).

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev You mean, there *are* any morphological reasons for applying GG? Well, then you have to explain what morphological reasons you find, which make `aerosol` **feminine**, but `alcohol` **masculine** in Russian. :)

Comment: @bytebuster Yes, that's the case that is interesting from the point of view of the original question: the morphological patterns allow ambiguous declension class for such nouns, hence other rules (of the kind the OP is for) emerge for our observation even in Russian.

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev They are everywhere: `toroid` and `spheroid` (**masculine**) versus `sinusoid` and `trapezoid` (**feminine**).

Comment: Re `sinusoid` for those unfamiliar with Russian: there is a corresponding Russian word with a feminine ending: `sinusoida`. Yes, I agree, for some reason the borrowing "wanted" to be feminine despite its phonetic form matching a different pattern, and an ending was added...

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev Correct, the same for `трапеция`. There were no morphological reasons to make them feminine at the moment of borrowing, correct? It has been borrowed from Latin `trapezium`, while other words ending with `-ium` are usually masculine (`Calcium`, `Lithium`). And the same for words ending with `-id`.

Comment: @bytebuster Interesting, the original Greek `trapezion` also wasn't feminine, was it? And German [`Trapez`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapez_%28Geometrie%29) also can't account for the source of feminine. Greek `trapeza` seems like being feminine, but that's too indirect for being the source of the gender in Russian probably...

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev I think, we're running too far away from the subject. Is there any evidence for scientific terms to be borrowed into Russian from Greek or German (not Latin)? My whole point is to understand why *"Russian and Ukrainian could be viewed as **not** being languages..."*

Comment: @bytebuster I agree with your doubt. And your arguments and examples in the comments here are supporting this view even on Russian and Ukrainian quite well. It's interesting.

Comment: As for borrowing of scientific terms: I believe that many were borrowed from German (although the source was Latin). This was the case for `Trapezium` [according to Vasmer](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=\data\ie\vasmer&first=1&off=&text_word=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&method_word=substring&ic_word=on&method_general=substring&ic_general=on&method_origin=substring&ic_origin=on): "Через нов.-в.-н. Тrареzium -- то же из ср.-лат. trapezium, греч. τραπέζιον, буквально "столик" (см. Хайзе; Даль 4, 823)."

Answer (score 3):

I have also been wondering about the question of gender-assignment in connection with Urdu, which I think is an outstanding example in what concerns your question. Technically it is New Indian, but the vocabulary is - apart from the basic Indic stratum - very very heavily influenced from mainly three sources:

1. Arabic
2. Persian
3. English

Urdu itself distinguishes a (sort of default) masculine gender and a feminine gender. While Arabic is similar in respect to there being two genders - masc. and fem. - and the masculine being sort of a default gender, the other two sources of vocabulary do not distinguish gender.

Now this is just to give an idea, because as far as I know, loanword noun morphology in Urdu has not yet been studied extensively, the only available research I am aware of being a rather unhelpful dissertation ([The Morphology of Loanwords in Urdu: the Persian,
Arabic and English Strands](https://theses.ncl.ac.uk/dspace/bitstream/10443/1407/1/Islam%2c%20R.A.%2012.pdf)).

By the very situation of three different sources with or without gender, most of the items in the list in aaa's answer can be found. Persian nouns ending in -ه, which used to be pronounced in Persian as a short final -a, are pronounced in Urdu with a long final -ā and thereby resemble a class of native masculine words in -ā. They are therefore almost invariably masculine. This would be point 3 in the above list:

> If the borrowed word happens to have a suffix that the borrowing language uses as a gender marker, the suffix tends to dictate gender.

Similarly, Persian nouns with a final long -ī are classed as feminine in Urdu, since there is a class of femininae in -ī corresponding to the masculinae in -ā. These are not very frequent in Persian except from abstract nouns like هستی (existence) or نیستی (non-existence). One other example I found is تختی, sort of a diminutive, feminine in Urdu as well. The same thing happened to Arabic کرسی (chair), which is masculine in Arabic, but then feminine in Urdu.

An easy example for point 2 in the list

> The borrowed word tends to take the gender of the native word it replaces.

would be the arabic word شمس (sun), which is feminine in Arabic, but masculine in Urdu, corresponding to the native words روی (रवि) and سوریه (सूर्य), the same is maybe true for Persian روز (day), which is masculine by default or via دن (दिन).

As to point 4

> If the borrowed word rhymes with one or more native words, the latter tend to dictate gender.

it is hard to find an example which is for sure assigned a certain gender due to rhyming. But it may be noted, that even words which are phonemically identical like کان (Urdu: ear; Persian: mine) can differ in gender, the ear being masculine and the mine being feminine, in agreement with the predecessor of the native word, Skt. खानि, feminine. This indicates that at least in the case of Urdu, the "native gender" is stronger than the rhyming.

Unfortunately the coverage of English loans in the dictionaries I have is still very bad, since English loans, I guess, are still viewed as just a manner of speech that does not partake of "good Urdu", or rather "pure Urdu". But what is still interesting, is the handling of Arabic nouns, since Arabic has more or less the same system of genders.

Here we can note, that participles are by default masculine like in Arabic and the feminine forms are borrowed along with the masculine ones, e.g. عالم and عالمة or معشوق and معشوقة. But the verbal nouns do differ in gender, for example all the nouns from stem II of the form تفعیل are feminine in Urdu. This I guess, may be due to a general tendency of abstract nouns being feminine (maybe already in Sanskrit: suffixes -ता (f) and -त्व (neuter)).

It would be great, if someone had even more information and examples on that.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's based on how the borrowed/new word sounds compared to existing words. For example, in French words ending in -age are typically male. But in German, the borrowed word "garage" became "die garage" - female. (E.g. die Frage, die Lage)

Comment: You might be partially right, but the example you selected to illustrate it is rather poor: the "g" in Garage is soft /ʒ/ [ɡaˈʀaːʒə], and hard in Frage [fʀaːɡə] and Lage [laːɡə].  It would work well in Portuguese though: *embraiagem*, *garagem* both feminine after *viagem* for instance .

Answer (score 1):

According to Ibrihim, 1973, p.61:

1. If the noun is animate, natural gender tends to dictate grammatical gender.
2. The borrowed word tends to take the gender of the native word it replaces.
3. If the borrowed word happens to have a suffix that the borrowing language uses as a gender marker, the suffix tends to dictate gender.
4. If the borrowed word rhymes with one or more native words, the latter tend to dictate gender.
5. The default assignment is the borrowing language's unmarked gender.
6. Rarely, the word retains the gender it had in the donor language.

Also, sometimes the choice is totally arbitrary, and may be different indifferent dialects. It may also change with time.

Comment: I'm seeing multiple papers from Ibrihim in 1973. Could you edit your question to say which paper you are citing? Maybe try to find a link on Google Scholar.

Answer (score 0):

In Swedish there are two grammatical genders, *neutrum* and *utrum*. Most nouns are categorized as *utrum* which is a merge of masculine and feminine genders in modern Swedish. New words are almost always *utrum*.

Comment: Björn, welcome to Linguistics! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers. Please expand your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor and/or repetitive answers risk being down-voted. Pay a special attention to how the new loanwords get their grammatical gender in Swedish. "Almost always mostly *utrum*" does not seem to be that helpful for the original question.

Comment: Easy counter-examples: "ett set", "ett disko", "ett aber".  On the other hand, the list of neologisms from 2012 http://www.sprakradet.se/nyordslistor (PDF link on the page) has a handful of new nouns which are all uters, though apparently mainly so because they follow established patterns.

Answer (score -3):

In Russian anything ending -а is feminine, anything ending -о and -е are neuter and anything ending with a consonant is masculine. Abbreviations case is determined based on the main noun in the abbreviation (this is the rule), but sometimes the speakers also apply the usual rules to the abbreviation as well, that is determine the gender based on the pronunciation, for instance "НАТО" ("NATO") is often used as neuter because of the -O ending, ВУЗ already became masculine this way. This happens mostly with familiar, often-used abbreviations which gradually become accepted as nouns.

The only remaining cases are the words ending with -и, -у whose gender is usually determined by the class to which the noun refers (city, river, organization).

There are multiple exceptions though.

Comment: Russian could be viewed as not being a language "with grammatical gender that has (almost) no morphological relation between the words and the genders(e.g. French)".

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev, you probably should elaborate on that for us, the unenlightened.